# What Docker image do I choose that support python and install zbar shared library?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, zbar

I am trying to deploy my python app in a docker container. The application uses pyzbar package for QR decoding.

On a Mac, I use `brew install zbar` to install the shared libraries and in my requirements file, I have

```
pypng==0.20220715.0
pyzbar==0.1.9
PyQRCode==1.2.1
```

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

RUN apt install python-zbar
```

the output of the last file is:

```
ERROR [2/8] RUN apt install python-zbar                                                                                                                                                            0.2s
------
 > [2/8] RUN apt install python-zbar:
#5 0.186 
#5 0.186 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#5 0.186 
#5 0.188 Reading package lists...
#5 0.194 Building dependency tree...E: Unable to locate package python-zbar
#5 0.195 
#5 0.195 Reading state information...
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt install python-zbar]: exit code: 100
```

Does anyone know a Docker Image that will support both?

Comment: what about `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [zbar docs](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/) for Linux you need to install `libzbar0` first, and then do a  `pip install pyzbar`. You can have to following Docker image which does this:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libzbar0 -y && pip install pyzbar
```

A little bit of explanation for `exit code: 100` error:

This error usually happens when the command, which you are running, is waiting for user input. For `apt-get install` you can pass the `-y` flag to avoid having `apt` to prompt for an user input.